# How do I remove the warning before deleting a shortcut?

Tags: windows, dialog

How do I remove the warning before *deleting a shortcut* in Windows?  Every time I want to delete a shortcut it warns me that I'm not actually deleting the program, just a shortcut.

Comment: Did you Right click the recycle bin, properties. Uncheck "Display delete confirmation dialog"

Comment: @Moab Isn't that for emptying the Recycle Bin...?

Comment: @Shinrai: No, it's not. Moab is right.

Comment: Oh, awesome.  That's a totally inane place to put it, then...!