# Are you sure you want to move this shortcut to the recycle bin?

Tags: windows-7

**EDIT:** A [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/203621/how-do-i-remove-the-warning-before-deleting-a-shortcut) has been asked, but does not address the unique function of drag and drop as distinct from other methods of deleting.

I'm running Windows 7. When I drag a program shortcut to the recycle bin, it pops up "Are you sure you want to move this shortcut to the recycle bin?" and gives me the sage advice that deleting the shortcut doesn't delete the program... well I'm not stupid and I already knew that, so I'd like it to stop telling me.

Btw, moving actual files (click and drag style) to the recycle bin produces no messages at all. I know I can disable all delete notifications from the recycle bin, but I really only want to disable *this* superpower that program shortcuts seem to have.

I searched Google and came up with only 15 results - none answered the question. I expect it's probably impossible without having a custom script running in the background, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: `CTRL`+`LEFT CLICK` and a Drag and Drop operation will skip the confirmation window.

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: And it's not a duplicate. The drag and drop part is unique. By default, drag and drop to the bin doesn't produce a notification - it is only with shortcuts of .exe files (which magically appear every once in while). And with those shortcuts, holding CTRL doesn't change anything.